# Will Anaconda's install of cudatoolkit and cudnn mess with my current configuration?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am trying to set up an anaconda virtual environment with tensorflow-gpu. When I go to install it, it says that it will also be installing cudatoolkit and cudnn, both of which I already have installed and configured on my machine. Will this mess with my existing configuration? Will this all be local inside of the virtual environment?

Note that the versions that it is asking to install are NOT the same as those already on my machine.

I currently have another virtual environment which runs tensorflow-gpu perfectly well, but it never asked me to install these packages.

For reference, I am running Ubuntu 18.04, Cuda 9.0, and cuDNN 7.0.3

Thanks for the help! I've spent a long time getting the packages configured correctly and don't want to have to start over.

Comment: You are right to fear this. I assume you tried. How did it go?

Comment: I installed it with pip and it seems like that didn't mess with my cuda installation. Pretty happy to have avoided having to reconfigure all of that nonsense.

Comment: @WNavidson1 Any updates or regrets on this? I too spent a nightmarish amount of time getting CUDA and cuDNN working properly and need to install Anaconda now.

Answer (score 3):

Anaconda `cudatoolkit` doesnt contain all the files which are included in a full CUDA install. Rather `cudatoolkit` includes the libraries which are redistributable and are used in downstream packages like Tensorflow, PyTorch, etc

[1] https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9676